# Why is this menu items disappearing when the browser is re-sized?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Site: https://borealisproductions.ca/

When the browser is re-sized the phone number on the left side of the page disappears, but the navigation menu on the right side of the page is responsive.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Because you div is display none

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are the envolved lines in your CSS document:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
.phone-number-custom {
    display:none!important;
}
```

It fix a breakpoint and removes the  with that class, that's why it "disappear".
You can eliminate the rule, or fix it on onother breakpoint, for instance 768px:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.phone-number-custom {
    display:none!important;
}
```

anyway that's up to your needs...

Comment: It worked, but now I'm having a problem where the entire menu disappears.

At some point as the browser window is sized smaller the nav menu on the right (Home/Video/Contact) is replaced by an on-click menu (top left corner). This also makes the phone number on the left side of the page out of place.

How can I prevent the menu from disappearing, or make the resolution it does disappear at smaller?